# Perl HTTP Request POST fails with TeamCity REST API

Tags: perl, http, rest, post, teamcity

I've got a perl script backing up our TeamCity server via the REST API as follows:

```
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw{ POST GET }

# ... code ommitted for brevity ... #

my $url = 'http://teamcity:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup';
my $req = POST( $url . '?includeConfigs=true&includeDatabase=true&includeBuildLogs=true&fileName=' . $filename);   
$req->authorization_basic($username, $password);
my $resp = $ua->request($req);
```

I tried posting the content more in line with the documentation for HTTP:Request, but for some reason it fails, complaining that I haven't specified a file name:

```
# This fails
my $req= POST( $url, [ 'includeConfigs'   => 'true',
                            'includeDatabase'  => 'true',
                            'includeBuildLogs' => 'true',
                            'fileName'         => $filename, 
                          ] );
```

Yet, when I look at the backend REST log for TeamCity, the full request seems to have made it intact, and is identical to the one that passes above.

Log of successful command:

```
[2012-12-13 15:02:38,574]  DEBUG [www-perl/5.805 ] - rver.server.rest.APIController - REST API request received: POST '/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup?includeConfigs=true&includeDatabase=true&includeBuildLogs=true&fileName=foo', from client 10.126.31.219, authenticated as jsmith
```

Log of failed command:

```
[2012-12-13 14:57:00,649]  DEBUG [www-perl/5.805 ] - rver.server.rest.APIController - REST API request received: POST '/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup?includeConfigs=true&includeDatabase=true&includeBuildLogs=true&fileName=foo', from client 10.126.31.219, authenticated as jsmith
```

Is there any other hidden difference between the two methods of making a POST request that could be causing the failure?

UPDATE:  Here is the result of each request when printed via Data::Dumper

Successful POST:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             '_content' => '',
             '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'http://teamcity:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup?includeConfigs=true&includeDatabase=true&includeBuildLogs=true&fileName=foo')}, 'URI::http' ),
             '_headers' => bless( {
                                    'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                    'content-length' => 0,
                                    'authorization' => 'Basic c3lzQnVpbGRTeXN0ZW1JOnBhaWQuZmFpdGg='
                                  }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
             '_method' => 'POST'
           }, 'HTTP::Request' );
```

Unsuccessful POST:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
             '_content' => 'includeConfigs=true&includeDatabase=true&includeBuildLogs=true&fileName=foo',
             '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'http://teamcity:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup')}, 'URI::http' ),
             '_headers' => bless( {
                                    'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                    'content-length' => 75,
                                    'authorization' => 'Basic c3lzQnVpbGRTeXN0ZW1JOnBhaWQuZmFpdGg='
                                  }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
             '_method' => 'POST'
           }, 'HTTP::Request' );
```

Comment: Something doesn't add up here.  Are you sure the first log entry really corresponds to the failed command?  Try using something identifiable in the command that fails, like a different filename, and see if it produces the log entry you expect.

Comment: If you could only see how much hair I have pulled out of my head while checking and double checking the same... ;-)  The log output is only showing the request URI TeamCity claims to have received... so there must be some more subtle difference.

Comment: Just to clarify: you are using `HTTP::Request::Common`?

Comment: Yes - 
use HTTP::Request::Common qw{ POST GET };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your server-side script can only handle `GET` parameters encoded in the URL, not `POST` data transmitted via standard intput. Note that there are several different methods described by HTTP, these are `GET`, `POST`, `HEAD`, `DELETE` etc. And then there are two ways of passing data to an application on the server. Most often one of those ways is also called `GET parameters` and the other one is called `POST data` because the `GET parameters` are usually used with the HTTP `GET` method and `POST data` is usually used for the HTTP `POST` method. However, they don't have to. And I think you're mixing up the HTTP `POST` method with `GET parameters` in the successful case and with `POST data` in the unsuccessful case.

`GET parameters` are passed via the URL by, most often by appending `?` to the URL followed by the actual key/value pais. Those are available via certain environment varialbes to the script running on the server. It's up to the script to split the variables at the `&`, split key/value pairs on `=` and undo the escaping.

For `POST data` the environment variable `CONTENT_LENGTH` tells the script how many bytes to read from its standard input. The actual key/value pairs are transmitted via a different encoding, usually as multipart encoded content. Yes, `POST` HTTP requests (mostly from HTML `<form>`s) can also be sent URL-encoded like `GET parameters`, but there's a length limit imposed by the HTTP standard on the URLs including all parameters. Hence the method of transferring the data via standard input, and not via the URL.

Now it looks like your server-side script can evaluate URL-encoded parameters (aka. `GET parameters`) parameters but not data posted to it via standard input. Even though you use the `POST` HTTP method/verb you don't actually transmit the values as `POST data` via standard input in your successful case. You could simply swap `POST(...)` for `GET(...)` in that case and it should still work.

In your unsuccessful case you use the `POST` HTTP method and the `POST data` way of transmitting the values.

My verbiage here may be wrong in cases, but the fundamentals should still be OK.

Comment: Just to be clear: have I misread the TeamCity documentation (http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin), or should I be raising a bug with them?  :-)

Comment: They're indeed mixing the `POST` HTTP method with `GET parameters` style parameter passing for the backup method invocation according to their example. That is perfectly valid, mind you, you did indeed misread the documentation, or you assumed their framework would handle `GET parameters` the same as `POST data` (which it doesn't -- other frameworks do, though) or you were simply not aware of the differences between the two styles of passing parameters.

Comment: Additionally: you will have to use the `POST()` Perl method in Perl but encode the parameters in the URL, just like you did already in the case that already worked for you.

Comment: I was working on an assumption, having successfully written Perl scripts to access other REST APIs (e.g. Nexus and JIRA)... and to be honest, had also forgotten the significance of the two different styles of passing parameters.  thanks for clarifying it :-)

Comment: You're welcome. A lot of frameworks don't differentiate how parameters are passed and offer the same API for accessing them; so I can understand perfectly that you forgot about it.

Answer (score -1):

```
my $url= my $url = 'http://teamcity:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/server/backup';
my $req= POST( $url, { 'includeConfigs'   => 'true',
                            'includeDatabase'  => 'true',
                            'includeBuildLogs' => 'true',
                            'fileName'         => $filename, 
                          } );
```

Note the '{}' (hash ref, not array ref). Also not mixing the Query String (GET) syntax with the POST syntax goes a long way towards clarifying the issue.

Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunately, switching to '{}' made no difference.  I was using an array ref as per http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Message-6.06/lib/HTTP/Request/Common.pm.

Comment: I thought the same thing, but the documentation has it as an arrayref and the code loops through as if it is an arrayref.